# How to use conditional filter and map with stream()

Tags: java, java-8, mapping, java-stream

I am trying to stream a `List` of Type A and based on conditions, map them to another Object of Type B.

Below is the structure of my classes.

```
public class A {
       private String   color;
       private Integer  actualValue;
       private Integer  expectedValue;
}

public class B {
       private Green green;
       private Yellow yellow;
       private Red red;
}


public class Green {
       private Integer  actualValue;
       private Integer  expectedValue;
}
```

... and the same structure of class Green, for class Yellow and Red as well.

My expectation is to use one `listA.stream()` and do the below mapping:

```
if(colorFromListA.equals("green") {
  //then set the "actualValue" from ListA to "actualValue" of 
    Class Green
}
else if (colorFromListA.equals("yellow") {
  //then set the "actualValue" from ListA to "actualValue" of Class Yellow
}
```

....and so on.

I have tried using the `.filter()` and `.map()` but however I am not sure how to use conditions in filter and do different mapping.

Can someone please assist.

Comment: So you've got a list of `A` objects, and you want to stream over it, and get the `actualValue` attribute of `B` and set it to `A`'s `actualValue` correct? But none of the field are `static`, so each objects `actualValue` can be different. Off of what object do you want to get the `actualValue` from?

Comment: And after mapping them to different objects what is your conclusive intent? What do you want to do with them, store them in a list of different Greens, Yellows etc?

Comment: @GBlodgett : I need to stream a List of A objects, check if the color = green, then get the actualValue from A and set it to actualValue of Class Green. Similarly if the color = yellow, then get the actualValue from A and set it to actualValue of Class Yellow

Comment: @Naman After mapping them my final result should be an Object of Type B. So inside B, I have the Class Green, Yellow and Red of whom the actualValue and expectedValue needs to be set.

Comment: @ShrutBiswas Yes, but again, the fields aren't static, so each instance of `Green` or `Yellow` will have it's own variable `actualValue`. So you cannot set `actualValue` of class `Green`, you can only set `actualValue` of an *instance* of class `Green`

Comment: @ShrutBiswas What if the there are multiple "green" in `listA`, how do you plan to map then to the object `B` which has only one `Green` attribute?

Comment: @Naman : My database from where I retrieve the List<A> will only be having 1 record of Green, 1 record of Yellow and 1 of Red.

Comment: Alright, iterate through them and map them using a converter method. Aside: In the current context, the existence of different color classes makes not much sense. You could have simply had a `class Color {private Integer  actualValue;
       private Integer  expectedValue;}` and then used it in B as `public class B {
       private Color green;
       private Color yellow;
       private Color red;
}`, this would then have required a single converter to convert the values and while setting them to attributes you could have matched it based on the `color` value.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 3 `A`s (one for each color) and want to combine them into 1 `B`?

Comment: @user1803551 yes correct

Comment: Why would you have multiple classes with the same structure? Also, none of this makes any sense.

Comment: If you have 3 `A`s why would you stream over them? Just do it proceduraly.

Answer (score 0):

The construction of a single `B` instance is not a task suitable for “[*Classes to support functional-style operations on streams of elements, such as map-reduce transformations on collections.*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)”. However, when your input is a `List` of `A` elements, which is not really a good input to your task, you may use the Stream API for a preparation step:

```
Map<String, A> colorToA = listOfA.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getColor, Function.identity()));

if(colorToA.size() != 3 ||
   !colorToA.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList("red", "green", "yellow")))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected [\"red\", \"green\", \"yellow\"],"
                                     + " but got "+colorToA.keySet());

B b = new B(new Red(   colorToA.get("red")   .getActualValue()),
            new Green( colorToA.get("green") .getActualValue()),
            new Yellow(colorToA.get("yellow").getActualValue()));
```

Note that if `Red`, `Green`, and `Yellow` have an identical structure and behavior, it’s questionable, whether you really need different classes for them. Only in some cases, the semantic difference might be worth separating them to prevent mixing them up (I assume, your question’s code is a simplified example).